# Setting image in same line as text

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have the line

```
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{{\LARGE\textbf{\name}}}\hfill\begin{figure}[ht!]\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{MyPic.jpg}\end{figure}
```

I want the "name" variable to be on the left, and the image to be on the right of the page. But it turns out the image goes on the left of the next line. How can I make it be in the same line as the "name", but to the right?

EDIT: Removing the `begin{figure}`

```
{\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{{\LARGE\textbf{\name}}}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{MyPic.jpg}
```

yields the same result.

Comment: Your `\parbox` is set to fill `\textwidth`, which leaves no room to place the image against the right margin. Just set `\noindent{\LARGE\textbf{\name}}\hfill\includegraphics[..]{...}%`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `figure` environment if not using `caption`. `figure` is a float and moves around. You don't need `\parbox` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{name} \hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

[image]